# Error in JSON array comparison customization(sky-screamer)

Tags: json, java-8, customization, junit5, assertj

I have below two JSONs to compare,

**expected json:**

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": null,
    "lastModifiedOn": null

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": null,
    "lastModifiedOn": null
  }
]
```

**actual json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": "2019-12-31",
    "lastModifiedOn": "2019-12-31",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": "2019-12-31",
    "lastModifiedOn": "2019-12-31",
  }
]
```

Trying to compare by ignoring couple of nodes using below code

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(actualjson, expectedjson,
new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.STRICT, 
    new Customization("createdOn", (o1, o2) -> {
        return true;
    }), 
    new Customization("lastModifiedOn", (o1, o2) -> {
        return true;
    })
)));
```

but it is failing with below assertion exception,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [0].createdOn
Expected: null
     got: 2019-12-31
 ; [0].lastModifiedOn
Expected: null
     got: 2019-12-31
 ; [1].createdOn
Expected: null
     got: 2019-12-31
 ; [1].lastModifiedOn
Expected: null
     got: 2019-12-31
```

how can I compare array of json values with customization object by skipping createdon and lastmodifiedon nodes?

```
<groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
```

Comment: change JSONCompareMode.STRICT to JSONCompareMode.LENIENT.

Comment: @KunalVohra LENIENT will ignore nodes completely, adding any extra nodes in future response contract will not fail test cases with this property.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes below code snippet**

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(actualjson, expectedjson,
new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.STRICT, 
    new Customization("**.createdOn", (o1, o2) -> true), 
    new Customization("**.lastModifiedOn", (o1, o2) -> true)
)));
```

Eventually Customization.getCustomization method invoke appliesToPath method , which invoke this.path.matcher(path).matches();

matcher method is from java.util.regex , so if your pattern "**.createdOn" matches with path "[0].createdOn" , "[1].createdOn" then your Customisation will be added CustomComparator which inturn call your method "(o1, o2) -> true"

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: Parse the JSON and recreate the two object JSONs without the date properties.

Approach 2: Parse the JSON and put an assertion on each property to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) it allows you to [ignore values, elements or path](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit#ignorevalues) which should help.

Answer (score 0):

Since SkyScreamer has open issue noted in github I found temporary solution and thought would be helpful for others,

https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/issues/109

**solution**:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    List<DomainObject> actualDomainObj = mapper.readValue(actualJson, new TypeReference<List<DomainObject>>() {
    });
    List<DomainObject> expectedDomainObj = mapper.readValue(expectedJson, new TypeReference<List<DomainObject>>() {
    });
    assertDomainObjResults(actualDomainObj.get(0), expectedDomainObj.get(0));


private void assertDomainObjResults(DomainObject actual, DomainObject expected) {
    softAssertions.assertThat(actual.getId()).isEqualTo(expected.getId());
    softAssertions.assertThat(actual.getLastModifiedOn()).isEqualTo(LocalDate.now());
    softAssertions.assertThat(actual.getCreatedOn()).isEqualTo(LocalDate.now());
}
```

accept the answer if someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a custom comparator that lets you use regular expressions in the 'expected' JSON:

```
public class ExtendedJsonComparator extends DefaultComparator {
    public ExtendedJsonComparator(JSONCompareMode mode) {
        super(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public void compareValues(String prefix, Object expectedValue, Object actualValue, JSONCompareResult result) throws JSONException {
        String expected = expectedValue.toString().trim();
        String actual = actualValue.toString();
        if(expected.startsWith("${") && expected.endsWith("}")) {
            String regex = expected.substring(2, expected.length() - 1);
            if(!actual.matches(regex)) {
                result.fail(prefix, expected, actual);
            }
        } else {
            super.compareValues(prefix, expectedValue, actualValue, result);
        }
    }
}
```

For 'expected, you can then do the following, or create a regex to match your date format, if that's something you're testing:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": "${.*}",
    "lastModifiedOn": "${.*}"

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": 1,
    "createdOn": "${.*}",
    "lastModifiedOn": "${.*}"
  }
]
```